# Making a REST service in .net and using it from android:

Tags: android, .net, rest, service

I am making a REST service in .net and using it from android.

The service is running well, i can see it from postman, and it is published in IIS too. But, i have a dude: I want to debug the service from visual studio and if I run it and the internal server of visual studio is running i can send gets from a browser like this: `localhst:3554/api/personas` but if I write `ip:3554/api/personas` the result is

**Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.**

And from Android the same. My objective is to debug from Visual Studio the request from Android but it doesn't work with localhst:3554 or ip:3554 (if i use IIS the ip works).

**Resume:**

- If I use `localhst:3554/api/personas` from a browser works for the internal server of vStudio.
- If I use  `ip:3554/api/personas` from a browser does not work.
- If I put any of the before sentences from android doesn't work.

All before for the internal server of vstudio that runs when you ejecute the service. If i use IIS all is well buy i can't debug!.

It's very simple the question but i don't know if i you can understand it well.

Thank you.

Comment: The firewall is disable for lan and wan...

why a request (get, post...) with my ip or writting "localhost" works for IIS and for the internal server of visual studio (runs when you execute the service on it) does'nt work my ip (bad request) and only works localhost??. This is the first problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall. It might block your external access to the service.